# Fourier series period from fft?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I have two arrays of discrete real data, x and y. X has integers along a regular interval, and y ranges from 0 to 1. I suspect some cyclicality in y, so I'm applying a fourier transform and plotting the results and real data as follows:

```
fx = np.fft.fft(x)
plt.plot(x, fx, color='red')
plt.scatter(x, y, color='blue')
```

The problem is I don't understand exactly what fft(x) returns. I see it's an array of complex numbers which probably represent the coefficients of the series, but I don't understand how to extract the period that best represents the cycles of y. Also, if the elements of fx are the coefficients, what exactly am I plotting here? Why does the length of fx equal the length of x?
Does fft assume the period is the length of x?

Comment: The FFT produces the same number of outputs as it gets in inputs. The more samples you feed it, the better granularity you get for frequencies. The center of the plot will be the frequency 0 (DC) level. To do something useful with the complex numbers you can square them, which throws away phase information but you don't care about that.

Comment: Clearly it does, but what are the outputs? If I want to plot functions 1, 2, 3, etc., how do I get those and their respective periods?

Comment: "To do something useful with the complex numbers you can square them" is just wrong, squaring the complex number is unhelpful.   Usaully we look a magnitude and phase ( the arg of the complex fft  number), sometimes squaring the magnitude helps picking out spectal peaks by eyeball.     To reduce spectal spreading, improve selectivity of frequency components the data is often windowed - multiplied by a function that smoothly tapers it to zero at the beginning and end of the sequence

Comment: @f5r5e5d The question indicates they're looking for cyclicality, which to me implies searching for peak amplitudes in frequency without regard to phase. That's the only reason I recommended squaring, and I actually meant the absolute square. Your comment about windowing is dead on.